# Data transferred from observable not showing in interpolation

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, behaviorsubject

**I have following service:**

```
  private vulnerabilityDescriptionSource: BehaviorSubject<
    VulnerabilityDescription
  > = new BehaviorSubject(new VulnerabilityDescription());
  public vulnerabilityDescription: Observable<
    VulnerabilityDescription
  > = this.vulnerabilityDescriptionSource.asObservable();

  public getVulnerabilityDescriptions(vulerabilityId: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<VulnerabilityDescriptionResponse>(
        Endpoints.getvulnerabilityDescriptions(vulerabilityId)
      )
      .subscribe(
        (vulnerabilityDescriptionResponse: VulnerabilityDescriptionResponse) =>
          vulnerabilityDescriptionResponse.data.vulnerabilityDescription
      );
  }
```

**I call the service like this:**

```
  public vulnerabilityDescription: Observable<VulnerabilityDescription> = this
    .vulnerabilityService.vulnerabilityDescription;  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vulnerabilityService.getVulnerabilityDescriptions(this.vulnerability.type);

  }
```

When I open the page I can see the correct data being transferred in the network tab. 
My issue is that when I want to access the data via interpolation in my html nothing appears there is no error or anything.

**This is how i try to display the data:**

```
      <div *ngIf="vulnerabilityDescription | async as vulnerabilityDescription">
        {{vulnerabilityDescription.shortdescription}}
      </div>              
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active"  [attr.id]="'v'+vulnerability.id+'description'" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
          {{(vulnerabilityDescription | async )?.shortdescription}}
```

What am I missing?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the .subscribe on your component.ts beacuse you have access to the data only inside the

```
.subscribe((result:VulnerabilityDescriptionResponse) =>{
//what i want to do whit the result from the call
this.vulnerabilityDescription = result;
}
```

So to fix your problem your service have to become

```
 private vulnerabilityDescriptionSource: BehaviorSubject<
    VulnerabilityDescription
  > = new BehaviorSubject(new VulnerabilityDescription());
  public vulnerabilityDescription: Observable<
    VulnerabilityDescription
  > = this.vulnerabilityDescriptionSource.asObservable();

  public getVulnerabilityDescriptions(vulerabilityId: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<VulnerabilityDescriptionResponse>(
        Endpoints.getvulnerabilityDescriptions(vulerabilityId)
      );
  }
```

In your component.ts

```
import { yourServiceClassName} from "where is the service";

export class Component implements OnInit {

    //inject your service
    constructor(private yourService:yourServiceClassName) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.yourService.subscribe(result =>{
    this.vulnerabilityDescription = result;
    }

}
```

In your template component.html

Remove the `| async` from it

And it should work